# Creating DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

How would I dynamically create a `DateTime` object, that always has what the current month/day/year is, but always has the 16:00 time component?

Comment: Be careful; you want to make sure that you make a deliberate decision about whether you want 4pm in the local time zone or 16:00 GMT. 24 out of 25 timezones will be different from yours ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 var today = DateTime.Today.AddHours(16);
```

That should be whatever today is at 16:00 (4pm)

Comment: While both answers I correct, I like @Tejs better since it only calls DateTime.Today once.  That way it doesn't have to generate Today 3 times.  (Today resolves to DateTime.Now.Date)

Comment: @James Michael Hare: updated my response - I highly doubt it makes any significant difference - but hey.....

Comment: @marc_s: I'd imagine it's similar to many other performance debates.  A call here or there you won't see the difference, but if it's performed repeatedly could add overhead, albeit small.  Like I said, both are correct, I just liked the elegance of the Today.AddHours(16)

Comment: After further analysis, AddHours is only a hair more efficient.  One million iterations of each yielded 1570 ms for AddHours() and 1883 ms for new DateTime() methods.  So either is really so close as to be almost negligible.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime Today16 = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day,
                                16, 0, 0)
```

That should use the year, month, day of today, and set time to 16:00 hours.